# Python > Connection with JDBC to Oracle service name (jaydebeapi)

Tags: java, python, oracle, jdbc, jaydebeapi

This sample code is used to connect in Python to Oracle SID.

```
import jpype
import jaydebeapi
jHome = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
jpype.startJVM(jHome, '-Djava.class.path=/path/to/ojdbc6.jar')
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@DB_HOST_IP:1521:DB_NAME')
```

How can we connect to Oracle Service Name?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your connection string, you could use `TNS` syntax  ([read on, here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm)),
as opposed to `host:port:sid` syntax you're using now. 
In that case you would describe `SERVICE_NAME` inside `CONNECT_DATA`, as follows:

```
   jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','[MYUSER]/[MYPASS]@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[MYHOST])(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated) (SERVICE_NAME=[MYSERVICENAME])))')
```

By the way - you could also use [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1) to connect to oracle - no `java` hassle. (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 4):

This way should work

```
  conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@//DB_HOST_IP:1521/DB_NAME')
```