# Why can't I install jpype with pip?

Tags: python, pip

Seeing this article [connection to oracle with jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568378/python-connection-with-jdbc-to-oracle-service-name-jaydebeapi), I would also try this to connect to Oracle.
And then I tried to get 'jpype' with pip to import it on my module in advance.

But these message have appeared on my screen.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jpype (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jpype

Could someone help with this solution?[Messages on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4k4D.png)
My version of pip seems to be 20.0.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/JPype1/) for JPype we can see that the needed command is - `pip install JPype1` and not `pip install jpype`. Always remember to cross check the page to make sure you are using the right command to install packages

Comment: Thank you for prompt advise. I could see much progress, but unfortunately another problem has occured  again. If you can, please tell me what can I deal with this??     
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: @saya24 yes that is a common error. You need to have the Microsoft C complier installed and added to your PATH. There are a few other questions on stack overflow that better explain the error and it's solutions

Comment: I greatly appreciate your kindness! Finally I could get jpype after having the Microsoft C complier installed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @saya24 no problem